# Jest: Testing a nested promise

Tags: javascript, promise, jestjs

I'm new to jest, and having trouble determining how to test results nested inside promises. Specifically:

```
myMethod: function (e) {
  let self = this
  self.resetErrors()

  Parser.parseFile(this.form.uploadFile).then(res => {
    const hasErrors = self.validFile(res)
    if (!hasErrors) {
      self.processFile(res)
    }
  })
}
```

I'd like to test to ensure that, assuming `hasErrors` is false,  `self.processFile` fires. Here's my current (failing) best effort:

```
describe("if the provided data is valid", () => {
  it('runs processFile', () => {
    const mockProcessFile = jest.fn()
    mockParser = jest.fn(() => {
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return ValidMockData
      }).then((loanData) => {
        expect(mockProcessFile).toBeCalled()
      })
    })

    CsvParser.parseFile = mockParser

    wrapper.vm.validFile = jest.fn(true)
    wrapper.vm.processFile = mockProcessFile
    wrapper.vm.store().resolve((data) => {
      expect(mockProcessFile).toBeCalled()
    })
  })
})
```

At present I'm getting a `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` error - which makes sense, but I'm not sure how exactly I'm supposed to crack into expectations inside of a then() call. Any thoughts appreciated

Comment: first thing I noticed `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return ValidMockData
      })` ... promises need to be resolved or rejected ... returning some ValidMockData doesn't do it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to store the Promise you create in the test so you can use `await` to let the test finishing after it was resolved:

```
describe("if the provided data is valid", async() => {
  it('runs processFile', () => {
    const mockProcessFile = jest.fn()
    const p = Promise.resolve(ValidMockData)
    CsvParser.parseFile = jest.fn(() => p)


    wrapper.vm.validFile = jest.fn(true)
    wrapper.vm.processFile = mockProcessFile
    wrapper.vm.store()

    await p

    expect(mockProcessFile).toBeCalled()
    expect(mockProcessFile).toBeCalled()


  })
})
```